# Moving a ball to Random Coordinates in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, random

The story is that I have this research project in which I have to simulate a tracking experiment.

I have a ball in a box (which we hope can be implemented as a VR room in the future), and the ball moves to random coordinates.

I also plan on adding another object that the user can click on (or in the case of VR, use a joystick) to move and follow the ball.

The coordinates of each movement of the ball, and the coordinates of each movement of the object must be outputted to a file.

Right now, I am having difficulty sending the ball to random coordinates.

The ball is named "Player" and the file is named "PlayerController." The two issues are that while utilizing the Unity version of Random, I consistently attain the same coordinates on each run and the ball does not stop moving.

My code is attached below. Also, if any of you readers have an idea on how to implement the rest of my project, suggestions are definitely appreciated!

Thank you so much!

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {
    private float movementDuration = 2.0f;
    private float waitBeforeMoving = 2.0f;
    private bool hasArrived = false;
    private Coroutine moveCoroutine = null;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (!hasArrived)
        {
            hasArrived = true;



            Vector3[] v = new Vector3[20];




            for (int i=0; i<v.Length; i++)
            {
                Random.InitState(System.DateTime.Now.Millisecond);

                v[i] = new Vector3(Random.Range(-10.0f, 10.0f),
                Random.Range(-10.0f, 10.0f),
               Random.Range(-10.0f, 10.0f));

                moveCoroutine = StartCoroutine(MoveToPoint(v[i]));
            }


        }
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            StopMovement();
    }

    private IEnumerator MoveToPoint(Vector3 targetPos)
    {
        float timer = 0.0f;
        Vector3 startPos = transform.position;

        while (timer < movementDuration)
        {
            timer += Time.deltaTime;
            float t = timer / movementDuration;
            t = t * t * t * (t * (6f * t - 15f) + 10f);
            transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(startPos, targetPos, t);

            yield return null;
        }

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitBeforeMoving);
        hasArrived = false;
    }

    private void StopMovement()
    {
        if (moveCoroutine != null)
            StopCoroutine(moveCoroutine);
    }

    public void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("sphereTag"))
            StopMovement();
    }
```

Comment: I get different coordinates each run. The ball doesnt stop moving because you set `hasArrived` to false at the end of your coroutine so it just fires again every 2 seconds

Comment: So, @ryeMoss I deleted that last line for hasArrived, and it did solve the incessant paths problem.
Thank you so much for that.
However, I am still facing two issues:

1. The same path is displaying each run. Could this be due to the fact that I have a Mac?

2. I have an array of 20 vectors to move to, yet now the ball only moves to one point. How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The ball doesn't stop moving because you set hasArrived to false at the end of your coroutine so it just fires again every 2 seconds.

The coordinates were different for me every time - not sure what issue you are facing there. May be something with Random.InitState()

The way you have your loop set up, every vector in the array is getting fed into its own coroutine, but this is all happening essentially instantaneously since there is no delay before going into the next iteration of your for-loop. If you are attempting to loop through all 20 of the points you should instead call a single coroutine, with the for-loop and embedded delay inside:

```
bool hasArrived;
private float movementDuration = 2.0f;
private float waitBeforeMoving = 2.0f;

void Update()
{
    if (!hasArrived)
    {
        hasArrived = true;
        StartCoroutine(MoveToPoints());
    }
}

private IEnumerator MoveToPoints()
{
    Vector3[] v = new Vector3[20];

    for (int i = 0; i < v.Length; i++)
    {
        float timer = 0.0f;
        Vector3 startPos = transform.position;
        v[i] = new Vector3(Random.Range(-10.0f, 10.0f),
                Random.Range(-10.0f, 10.0f),
                Random.Range(-10.0f, 10.0f));

        while (timer < movementDuration)
        {
            timer += Time.deltaTime;
            float t = timer / movementDuration;
            t = t * t * t * (t * (6f * t - 15f) + 10f);
            transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(startPos, v[i], t);
            yield return null;
        }
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitBeforeMoving);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @ryeMoss! That allowed 20 paths, which is good.

However, I am still stuck in the sense that each run is the same for me. As I am using your modifications, do you have an idea of why this may be?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: honestly I would just try googling it and see what other people have tried. sorry I can't be any help here, have never run into that problem. I am seeing InitState in several places. maybe check to make sure you are using that correctly?